# Vertical scrollbar is hiding element with absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an element with absolute position that is being displayed over the vertical scroll, preventing the user from scrolling the page using the scrollbar.

[image: a busy cat]

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9du1y0o5/6/) explains the problem and what I'm currently doing.

This is the css I'm using to position the div.

```
.side-content {
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  height: calc(100% - 132px);
  width: 100px;
}
```

I was expecting the div to be positioned considering the scrollbar (without manually adding a margin) and not hovering it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

do `z-index: -50;`

```
.side-content {
  z-index: -50;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  height: calc(100% - 132px);
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cesar! That will just 'move' the div under the scrollbar. What I need is that the div is displayed  alongside the scrollbar. Thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .wrapper
  {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .inside_div_one
  {
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .inside_div
  {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .inside_div_two
  {
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
  }
  .inside_div_three
  {
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: grey;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inside_div_one">
        <p>sidebar</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inside_div_two">
        <p>FIRST</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>LAST</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inside_div_three">
        <p>jvsdfv</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```